# Xamarin throws Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException using CallRedirectionService

Tags: java, c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin.forms

I created a new Mobile App Xamarin.Forms project using the blank template for this example. I am trying to use CallRedirectionService in my app, but the following exception is thrown.

> Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException: crc64bf934172c93e128d.MyCallService ---> Java.Lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/telecom/CallRedirectionService; ---> Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.telecom.CallRedirectionService" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.companyname.xam-8bL_MB0IWItrj3Z69Zwvtw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.companyname.xam-8bL_MB0IWItrj3Z69Zwvtw==/lib/x86, /data/app/com.companyname.xam-8bL_MB0IWItrj3Z69Zwvtw==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib]]

```
using Android.Telecom;
using Xamarin.Forms;    
namespace xam
    {
        public class MyCallService : CallRedirectionService
        {
            public override void OnPlaceCall(Android.Net.Uri handle, PhoneAccountHandle initialPhoneAccount, bool allowInteractiveResponse)
            {
                //throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }
        public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
        {
            public MainPage()
            {
                var callCervice = new MyCallService();
                InitializeComponent();
            }
        }
    }
```

How can i solve it, since other service doesnt throw any exceptions

e.g.

```
public class CallPreventer : InCallService
{
    public override void OnCallAdded(Call call)
    {
        call.Disconnect();
        base.OnCallAdded(call);
    }
}
```

[Android options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSvKh.png)

[Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pU39v.png)

Comment: This might be being stripped out by the linker? What are your linker settings under Android Project properties -> Android Options? Are you using any code shrinker etc.?

Comment: All properties and options are default, shrinker is not used

Comment: I just noticed your screenshots -- it looks like you have added Android-specific code in your MainPage.cs code behind which presumably is in your shared project? If you want to use Android-specific stuff it should be in your Android project. To call it from your MainPage code behind use the Xamarin Forms Dependency Service (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the screen shots it looks like this code is part of the .NET standard assembly (shared project) which won't reference Mono Android. Instead, try using the [Xamarin Forms Dependency Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction) to invoke the platform-specific things you want from shared code. See [my recreation of your code here](https://github.com/aharwood2/DependencyServiceExample).